GUI for periodic backups (Linux)
I know there are plenty of backup applications out there, but unless I'm wrong I can't find one with the following simple features:

run in Ubuntu
possibly open-source (but not mandatory!)
it should just compress the folders I select, I'm not interested in sync or incremental backups (for that I'm already using FreeFileSync)
it must support remote destinations via (S)FTP(S)
it should provide a naming syntax (i.e. myproject-timestamp.zip)
support different profiles, to backup different folders
I don't want to restore the backup using the application. If needed I will manually inspect the zipped file

I tried:

FreeFileSync: it's great, but I wasn't able to just make a compressed file and upload it somewhere with a given (speaking) name
Déjà Dup: it does not provide a simple zip file
Grsync: it seems to allow only synchronization between folders
Back in time: it does not support FTP


Isn't this a scenario for a simple cronjob + tar -czf or zip command? I would be surprised if there's a GUI for that.. I mean there's the Archiver utility, which does what you want to do, as long as something else provides the sftp mapping, bug cronjob, ssh and tar can do it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95993/how-to-make-tar-save-the-archive-on-a-remote-machine-using-sftp-or-ftp . Naming with timestamp is also easily done.. $(date).

@Raf perhaps I'm wrong, but it requires a non-trivial script to achieve the features above. It needs to create the correct file name, handle the FTP connection, etc...

@Raf just seen your comment update. I'm looking at that link right now

It's not trivial in the sense that it's a 1 liner to paste & go, but it's "trivial" enough that there isn't a popular known GUI replacement for exactly this task, I suspect. I would be happy to be proven wrong though. 1) tar/zip the files 2) sftp it, it's two basic tasks with.. maybe 3) put it in cron.d
